# Key Lookup isn't applied by default?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, nonclustered-index, bookmark-lookup

I'm trying to learn about covering indexes. In the Northwind database, I select from the table *Categories*:

[image]

As you can see the table has a non-clustered index on the column *CategoryName*.

This SQL query:

```
select CategoryName  from Categories where Categories.CategoryName like 'Beverages'
```

returns an execution plan with an index seek:

[image]

However, this:

```
select CategoryName ,Description from Categories where Categories.CategoryName like 'Beverages'
```

returns this execution plan with an index scan using the primary key index, which isn't expected:

[image]

I can find the expected behaviour only when I force the query with the non-clustered index:

```
 select CategoryName ,Description from Categories
    with(index(CategoryName))
 where Categories.CategoryName like 'Beverages'
```

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: FYI - Northwind is a very obsolete sample database. It was designed for sql server 2000.  More recent samples are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Description` column in your index but there is in your query. So, SQL Server has to get this column. There are two options for doing that:

- non-clustered index seek + key lookup
- clustered index scan

If your statistics make SQL Server think it will read a lot of data, SQL Server makes a choice between the non-clustered index seek + key lookup or clustered index scan, this called tipping point.

Because, if SQL Server has to read huge data, the clustered index scan can be more efficient rather than non-clustered index seek + key lookup.

There is a good blog post [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/10/how-to-think-like-the-sql-server-engine-whats-the-tipping-point/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **Nonclustered Index** doesn't include `Description` so it doesn't **cover** the second query.

The only two options then are either use that **Nonclustered Index** and then do a **Key Lookup** on the **Primary Key** (effectively the **Clustered Index** in this case) to get the `Description` field (two operations) or just use the **Clustered Index** from the beginning to find and filter down the data, since the **Clustered Index includes** all fields (one operation).

It chooses one operation over the other depending on the difference in **Operator Costs** in the **execution plan** which will vary from query to query and dataset to dataset, depending on thing likes the **Cardinality** of the data.

This is known as [The Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/).

If you changed the **Nonclustered Index** to **include** the `Description` field then it should use the **Nonclustered Index** instead, in one operation (no **Key Lookup** even needed).

E.g:

```
DROP INDEX CategoryName ON Categories
CREATE INDEX CategoryName ON Categories (CategoryName) INCLUDE (Description)
```